# PDO basics, but I really don't understand :-(

Tags: php, select, pdo, execute, prepare

I'm really new to PDO, and I can't get this to work :

I want to check a captcha code. Every day, the asked code changes according to the day number. In my database, a table contains two columns: JOUR (=day) and REPONSE (=answer). The user inputs a code I store in $code_entre. This code has to be compared to the input one.

With the date() method, I get the day's number. I store it in $numero_jour. My code is supposed to get the code of the day and compare it to the input one. Here's the code :

```
            $numero_jour = date(j); //Récupère le numéro du jour en cours.

            $sql2 = $bdd1->prepare('SELECT JOUR FROM questions_securite WHERE REPONSE=:reponse LIMIT 1');

            $sql2->bindParam(':reponse', $code_entre, PDO::PARAM_STR);          
            $sql2->execute();
            $req2 = $sql2->fetch();

            $sql2->closeCursor(); 

            if($req2 != $numero_jour) {
                return 'Erreur de code de sécurité. Veuillez recommencer.';
            }
```

... and nothing happens ! I tried the "echo $req2 instruction, and all I get is the "Array" word.

What am I doing wrong ? I'm sure the solution is easy, but I don't find it out !

Thanks !

Comment: best you go back to the official manuals and worthy tutorials

Comment: Side note: make sure all error messages are used in a language that's universally understood, or the closest one to it. I'm obviously referring to English.

Comment: To see, what is in `$req2`, use `var_dump($req2)`, it tells You more.

Comment: Read the documentation for [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), of course it's echoing `Array` because it contains an array!

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your replies. I had read lots of pages about the use of PDO (php.net, php-manual.net, etc.) but I think the problem comes from my conception of the results the fetch() method retrieves. When I ask do fetch a peculiar data using WHERE in a two colums table, I expect to get a string from the other column. I don't think of using a loop to search the result, because I know that in this table, there's only one corresponding row. But in other cases, there may be several ones!

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) for PDO's *fetch* method:

> Fetches the next row from a result set

What this means is that **$req2** will not be a string but a row containing *key->value* pairs where the keys represent the columns in the row.

What this essentially means is you need to access the value of the columns within the row.

A given example in the documentation should help you in understanding how to achieve your goal:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
print $result->name;
```

In this case $result looks like, for example:

```
Array
(
    [name] => apple
    [colour] => red
)
```

It's been a while since I used PDO but one example I used at some point to iterate through many rows to fetch the value for a certain column for each row was like this, to help you if you need to check for multiple rows:

```
...

$sth ->execute();
$sth ->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$currentName = "";
while ($row = $sth ->fetch())
{
    $currentName = $row['name'];
}
```

This should be enough to get you started. Remember to use the documentations and highly rated tutorials to help you.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your detailed. I think the problem comes from my conception of the results the fetch() method retrieves. When I ask do fetch a peculiar data using WHERE in a two colums table, I expect to get a string from the other column. I don't think of using a loop to search the result, because I know that in this table, there's only one corresponding row. But in other cases, there may be several ones!
Your explanation gave me another point of view on the problem. I'm more at ease with JSON tables, but the approach is basically the same.
Many thanks !